# How to show secondaryText next to text in UIListConfiguration.valueCell()?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uilistcontentconfiguration

I am using `UIListConfiguration.valueCell()` for displaying two textual information in a single `UITableViewCell`. The `secondaryText` label is getting aligned to the trailing end of cell and is not nearby the `text` label. How to make the `secondaryText` label align to the trailing end of the `text` label ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set [prefersSideBySideTextAndSecondaryText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilistcontentconfiguration/3601039-preferssidebysidetextandsecondar).

Comment: Tried, not working for me.

Comment: I think the documentation linked to describes exactly what needs to be done to do what original poster asked to do? Do you mean that the property does not work at all, or that you expected something different from the final outcome?